# Java comparing files with BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

This is the method I'm trying to do:

```
static void filter( BufferedReader orders, BufferedReader in,
        BufferedWriter out ) throws IOException
```

The objective is to read a text file with the in reader, then check if the sentences contain the keywords that are stored in another text file with the orders reader, and if the sentences do contain those key words, write them down in another text file with out writer.

I have done this so far:

```
static void filter( BufferedReader orders, BufferedReader in,
        BufferedWriter out ) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader ordersf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("order_filter.txt"));
    BufferedReader inf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hamlet.txt"));
    BufferedWriter outf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out_filter.txt"));

    String line = inf.readLine();

    while(line != null){
        String filter = ordersf.readLine();
        if(filter.equals(line))
            outf.write("    "+line);
    }
    ordersf.close();
    inf.close();
    outf.close();
}
```

Now I have no clue on how to compare the key words contained in `order_filter.txt` with the sentences in `hamlet.txt`
I would appreciate some help.

Comment: How big are the files?  Is it possible to store the contents in memory?

Comment: The files are really small, thr larger one only has 27Mb, and it is possible yes.

Comment: Then I would suggest loading each file into a HashSet and then finding which keys in the first HashSet doesn't correspond to a key in the second.

Comment: I have not yet learned HashSet and thus i cant use it in this project, i am basically forced to use the buffereds

Comment: @TrippKinetics Wouldn't HashSet end up removing duplicate (if any) lines from the file?

Comment: Yes.  Any set would.

Comment: You could store keywords in a database or vcs file, this will take care of your split problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do it the dirty way then you can split the words from **ordersf** and see if each word is a substring of the sentence. So assuming your filter has words delimited by spaces then you could do something like:

```
String[] filter_words = filter.split(" ");

for(String filter_word : filter_words) {
    if(line.toLowerCase().contains(filter_word.toLowerCase())) {
        <<do something>>;
    }
}
```